# MVC3 view rendering twice when I have Glimpse and use a MVC control toolkit DateTimeFor element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have an MVC application with glimpse installed, I am also using the MVCControlToolkit for dymanic validation.

The issue I have is when I have a view that uses DateTimeFor to display the date time calendar with validation, but only in a very limited set of circumstances (if I only have datetimefor elements this doesn't happen), the body gets rendered on the page twice.

It looks like the rendering is getting restarted by something, but I haven't been able to work it out.

Any help would be appreciated

My view code is

```
    @using LeaveTracker.Models
@using LeaveTracker.Models.Leave
@using MVCControlsToolkit.Controls
@using MVCControlsToolkit.Controls.Validation
@model LeaveTracker.Models.Leave.LeaveAllocation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMaintenance.cshtml";
}

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="page-header">
<h1>    
    Edit Leave Allocation 
    @if (Model.ID > 0) { <small> @Model.TypeOfLeave.Name till @Model.AppliesUntil.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</small> } 
</h1>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.JQueryDatePickerGlobalizationScript("en-GB")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ValidationSetup.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MVCControlToolkit.Controls-1.5.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Leave Allocation Details</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOfLeave)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeOfLeave, 
                       LeaveFactory.GetAllLeaveTypes().Select(fl => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = fl.Name,
                            Value = fl.ID.ToString()
                        }))
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeOfLeave)</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppliesFrom)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.AppliesFrom, DateTime.Today, true).DateCalendar(
                    inLine: false,
                    calendarOptions: new CalendarOptions
                    {
                        ChangeYear = true,
                        ChangeMonth = true
                    })                  
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppliesFrom)</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

         <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppliesUntil)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.AppliesUntil, DateTime.Today, true).DateCalendar(
                    inLine: false,
                    calendarOptions: new CalendarOptions
                    {
                        ChangeYear = true,
                        ChangeMonth = true
                    })                
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppliesUntil)</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DefaultAllocation)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DefaultAllocation)
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefaultAllocation)</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Leave Carried Over</legend>

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxCarriesOver)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxCarriesOver)
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxCarriesOver)</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LeaveUseByDate)
            <div class="input">
                @Html.DateTimeFor(model => model.LeaveUseByDate, DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900"), true).DateCalendar(
                    inLine: false,
                    calendarOptions: new CalendarOptions
                    {
                        ChangeYear = true,
                        ChangeMonth = true
                    })               
                <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LeaveUseByDate)</span>
                <span class="help-block">The year on this field doesn't matter, only the month and day will be taken into account</span>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn" })            
            <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value='Save'>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer - new bits were released which hopefully will address your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lee,

We believe we have fixed this issue.

Can you please test and confirm by installing the alpha build of Glimpse 0.87 from MyGet at http://www.myget.org/F/getglimpse/

If we get confirmation that this fixes your issue - and with a bit more testing - we will release to the main NuGet.org repository.

**EDIT**
Glimpse version 0.87 is now available from the main [NuGet.org Glimpse feed](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse)

Comment: Sorry about the long reply. This seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks

Comment: Version 0.87 fixed my repeating body issue too, although I'm not using any DateTimeFor and just have a fairly dumb page of markup. Any idea when this is going to be released to the main nuget.org feed?

Comment: I have just pushed 0.87 to NuGet.org. Thanks!